# Resolution of NumberFoundException in Java

Tags: java, jdbc

I am new to Java and am experiencing a problem in resolving `NumberFormatException.`
The code which I tried to run is

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.lang.*;

public class NewClass {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            String connectionUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306" +
            "user=root&password=root";

            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
            Statement stmt = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;
            stmt = con.createStatement();
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("SQL Exception: "+ e.toString());
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException cE) {
            System.out.println("Class Not Found Exception: "+ cE.toString());
            }    
        catch(NumberFormatException ne)
        {
            System.out.println("NumberFormatException:"+ne.toString());
        }
    }

}
```

It is showing the error:

> SQL Exception:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException:
>   Cannot load connection class because of underlying exception:
>   'java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string:
>   "3306user=root&password=root"'.

What should I do?

Comment: Half the problem here is that you didn't even bother to read the error message correctly.

Comment: @EJP I didn't understand the error as I have already told you I am new to Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because your connection URL is wrong, you should have at least a ? after the port number.
Anyways it is better to use this code to get the connection:

```
String connectionUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306";
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl, "root", "root" );
```

Also remember to close your connections, resultset and statement in the finally block

Answer (score 0):

Your connectionUrl is missing a `?` to separate the port from the queryString:

`String connectionUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306?" +`

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this

```
try{

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DB_NAME","root","root");   
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error in connection"+e);
        }
```